Origin of "That tracks" to mean "That makes sense."
For the past few years, I have been hearing people say "that tracks," meaning "that makes sense."  My search on Green's Dictionary of Slang yielded nothing with this clear meaning, but I've found a lot of example usages by searching Google for terms like "that tracks because" or "which tracks because":

Flashback time again: Jeremiah is extremely upset about the Belly-Conrad thing, which tracks because if a girl I loved dated my brother instead, I would go insane.


"35 Thoughts I Had While Watching Season 2, Episode 1, of The Summer I Turned Pretty", Vogue


Apiros isn’t a typical gym, which tracks because Austin Einhorn isn’t a typical trainer.


Lookout Landing Podcast

I have not found a relevant definition in publicly available dictionaries like Merriam-Webster.
What is the origin of this expression, and how old is it?

The word tracks is synonymous with follows in that sense.

The first definition in the OED is "follow'

The sense of "to make sense" of the verb track goes back to 1924 in written usage per OED. Here is the definition and the first citation from OED:

intransitive. To be consistent with something (such as other information, expectations, prior experience, etc.); to fit; to make sense. colloquial (originally U.S.).
1924 I have carefully read the address... Upon all democratic questions, it tracks with established democratic policies..and is perfectly sound. 
Sedalia (Missouri) Democrat 12 August 8/3
Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “track (v.1), additional sense,” March 2024, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/7856344720.


+1 for a high-quality source, but I don’t think this shows that the “make sense” usage goes back to 1924 as you suggest.  The 1924 example is the form “X tracks with Y”, i.e. the sense “to be consistent with” — it doesn’t imply that the with-less form “X tracks” = “X makes sense” was in use by that date.  (Like others’ here, my intuition is that this usage is a later development from the “X tracks with Y” form — but of course, intuition is cheap, a corroborating source is what’s needed!)

@PLL you're looking for a difference that doesn't exist. "makes sense" is just "tracks with common sense".  every single word/phrase in English is used constantly with such breadth of meaning.  (in this field of meaning, think of cohesive, sensible, sound, solid, effective etc etc) Even in the example dug up in this excellent answer, the writer puts it with "perfectly sound"; it's all the same.

There has definitely been a usage change and an idiomatic shift, and I agree with @PLL . If someone said "I am gonna do it. Trust." 20 years ago it would've sounded off to most native ears but if you say "trust me" to most native speaking teenagers these days they will tell you you sound old. Fattie's comment doesn't make a lick of sense.

In my view, this is a figurative extension of the phrase "to track with X" which means "to follow along with X wherever X may go (remaining aligned with X)". It is used of trailers which are pulled by a truck or tractor. The trailers are said to "track with" the tractor or the truck. It seems rather like a calque on  "to comport".

DIFFERING from other types of semi trailers, the trailer produced by the Trailer Transportation Co., New York City, is the first commercial design in practice which tracks with the pulling truck or tractor.
The Commercial Vehicle, April 1915.


Interesting example from 1915. In this instance, "tracks with" may literally mean "follows in the same tire tracks as"—presumably because the trailer's axle is exactly the same length side to side as the truck or tractor's axles—but it would certainly provide a good starting point for "tracks with" in the figurative sense of "follows [from]."

From https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=does+not+track+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

The above (The Country Gentleman, July 15, 1901, in a column for advice from a veterinarian) has HIND LEG LAME . . .Does not step as far with that leg as with the other, and drags it slightly; does not “track” with the forward one, but swings it a little to the left. . .

…The farmer is searching for a metaphor. A common use of “track” in the previous 50 years is railroad track, which is what I think is the origin of a likely spontaneous use.

The Free Dictionary has this meaning of track as an idiom:

track


informal To be in agreement or accordance (with something); to concur with or corroborate some piece of information.


Usually used in negative constructions.


Her testimony doesn't track with the defendant's alibi.


The two sets of figures just don't track. I suspect they're trying to make their sales numbers look more impressive for their shareholders.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tracked+with
It’s interesting that the OED picks up this meaning as  filmmaking becomes a profession. A “tracking shot”, of which there are several kinds, is a shot used in filming—one that follows or moves with the subject. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_shot
This is quite different from the use of tracking related to keeping track of the location or actions of an animal or a person, whether physically or digitally, or even uses metaphorically like right track or wrong, on track or off, which predate movie-making by hundreds of years.

While interesting to mention, I'm not sure if you're aware, a track shot is so-called because you put the camera/tripod system on a track (ie, literally a train track, ie like matthews track or whatever https://csirentals.com/matthews-track-straight-8-foot-section/  Proaim brand  https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1485645-REG/proaim_tk_strs_00_stream_16_heavy_duty_cinema.html/

(I just noticed for that sense the OED says "[with reference to early filming when a camera was mobile by means of a track]")
